# Pusher: Cannot broadcast client event

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, webrtc, pusher

I'm developing a conference app with laravel 5 and I decide to implement a webRTC solution for that.
 So, I use Pusher for signaling stuff, but I have a prob: I'm using SimplePeerJs for the webRTC things, when I trigger an event (after subscribing and others stuff), I have the following err:

```
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Cannot broadcast client event (connection not subscribed to channel presence-chat)"}}}.
```

my code is:

```
Pusher.log = function(message) {
            if (window.console && window.console.log)
            {
                window.console.log(message);
            }
        };
        var currentUser = {
            nom: '{{ auth()->user()->first_name }}',
            id: {{ auth()->user()->id }},
            stream: undefined
        };
        var pusher = new Pusher('my_app_key', {
            authEndpoint: 'pusher/auth',
            auth: {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                },
                params: {
                    name: currentUser.name,
                    id: currentUser.id
                }
            }
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('presence-chat');

        var callback = function() {
            console.log('Channel members:', channel.members);
        };
        //
        channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', callback);
        channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function(PusherError){
            console.log(PusherError);
        });
        channel.bind('pusher:member_added', function(){
            console.log('Member Added');
        });
        channel.bind('pusher:member_removed', function(){
            console.log('Member Removed');
        });
        //peers stuff
        var peer = new SimplePeer({ initiator: true });

        peer.on('signal', function (data) {
            channel.trigger('client-signal-' + currentUser.id,
                    {
                        userId: currentUser.id,
                        data: data
                    });
        });

        peer.on('ready', function () {
            peer.send('hey peer, how is it going?')
        });
```

any ideas?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the Pusher client hasn't had a chance to connect and subscribe to the channel before the `peer.on('signal')` is being triggered. Did you try moving the peers stuff into the subscription callback ?

```
var callback = function() {
  console.log('Channel members:', channel.members);

  //peers stuff
  var peer = new SimplePeer({ initiator: true });

  peer.on('signal', function (data) {
    channel.trigger('client-signal-' + currentUser.id,
                {
                    userId: currentUser.id,
                    data: data
                });
  });

  peer.on('ready', function () {
    peer.send('hey peer, how is it going?')
  });
});
```

Comment: Thinks for the answer, I do what u recommended, this err appear now:
`Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4301,"message":"Rejected client event because of rate limiting. See the docs: pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#trigger-events"}}}`